Relation between roots of a polynomial and zeroes of its associated polynomial function
Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[X], f = a_0 + a_1X + \ldots + a_nX^n$ and consider associated polynomial function:
$$\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \, \tilde{f}(x) = a_0 + a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n.$$
It is true that $(X-a)^n | f \iff \tilde{f}(a) = \tilde{f}'(a)=\ldots = \tilde{f}^{(n-1)}(a)=0$ and $(X-a)^{n+1}\not{|}f \iff \tilde{f}^{(n)}(a) \ne 0$?
I think it's true. The reason would be correspondence between zeroes of $\tilde{f}$ and roots of $f$ (they are the same).

Sorry for deleting my previous comment; I wanted to add more detail. You can prove your statement (in particular it is true) by induction on the order of the zero, which need not depend on the degree of the polynomial.

I think the second equivalence is false if it is taken without first equivalence. Because $\implies$ can be false without first equivalence

I just meant the first equivalence is right. I don't see how the forward implication of the second equivalence follows from the first equivalence.

For the second equivalence to be true it will need to be $\tilde{f}(a) = \tilde{f}'(a) =\ldots = \tilde{f}^{(n-1)}(a) = 0$ and $(X-a)^{n+1} \not{|} f \iff \widetilde{f}^{(n)}(a) = 0$ isn't it?

And it's first equivalence also true for $f \in \mathbb{C}[X]$?

The second equivalence is the same as $(X-a)^{n+1}|f\iff f^{(n)}(a)=0$ which is clearly too strong in view of the first equivalence.

The first equivalence is true over any field of characteristic $0$ (or $> n$); it may be useful to use the algebraic derivative $(X^k)' = k X^{k-1}$ extended linearly. Note that $f - \tilde{f}(a) = (X - a) g$ for some $g$ and then $f' = (X - a) g' + g$.
